# How to reproduce logs about desktop freezing on second-click in Debian Stretch Gnome Wayland?

Tags: debian, desktop, wayland, testing

I experienced the following event after using Wayland 1 H first time. 
Do

1. Use the laptop one hour, close the lid, and use again etc.
2. second click on any PDF file.
3. choose open with some application.
4. GUI gets stucked. No menu opens.
5. File icons on the desktop also freeze.
6. System stays in such a state until you restart it again.

Reproduction of the event 11th Oct. 2017: 1 time out of 1 times.     2nd iteration going on.

I did not find a mentioning of such a freezing in Debian Wayland bug tracker [here](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/wayland) and bugzilla [here](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/buglist.cgi?bug_severity=blocker&bug_severity=critical&bug_severity=major&bug_severity=normal&bug_severity=minor&bug_severity=trivial&bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&bug_status=NEEDINFO&bug_status=PLEASETEST&list_id=279166&product=Wayland&query_format=advanced). 
I will make a report about the issue if I can get an idea in the logs what is causing it.

OS: Linux Debian Stretch 9.1
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA R4028T
Touchpad: FocalTechPS
Window manager: Gnome 3.22 on Wayland 1.17

Comment: Why you are sticking to Wayland? Gnome is itself heavy and wayland on it will cause lags and even deadlocks.

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal Because I see a lot of potential in the software, and want to contribute to its development.